# Using Event Names stored in a variable in VueJs

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2, vue-directives

In VueJS, a child component can emit an event, for example:

```
this.$emit('toggle-button')
```

In the parent, we can listen to this event as follows:

```
<my-component v-on:toggle-button="doSomething"></my-component>
```

This works great. But I have a requirement where the event name (in this case, toggle-button) is stored in a variable or Vuex store. So, I don't have the exact event name but a variable or store with the name of the event.

In such a case what would be the syntax for referring that that event name in the on-click directive?

For example, let say we have:

```
let eventName = 'toggle-button'
```

How can I use this variable (eventName) instead of the exact event name (toggle-button) in the following:

```
<my-component v-on:toggle-button="doSomething"></my-component>
```

Answer (score 1):

You could use [`$on(EVENT_NAME, CALLBACK)`](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/api/#vm-on) in this case:

```
// <my-component ref="foo" />
this.$refs.foo.$on(eventName, doSomething)
```

```js
Vue.component('my-component', {
  template: `<button @click="$emit('click', $event)">Click</button>`
});

new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  mounted() {
    const eventName = 'click';
    this.$refs.foo.$on(eventName, this.doSomething);
  },
  methods: {
    doSomething() {
      alert('clicked');
    }
  }
})
```

```html
<script src="https://unpkg.com/vue@2.5.17"></script>

<div id="app">
  <my-component ref="foo" />
</div>
```

Comment: Thank! I will try. And where should this code go in my parent template?

Comment: @asanas No problem :) The code should probably go in the `mounted()` lifecycle hook (see demo I just added).

Comment: Don't forgot to also deregister the event handler when its no longer needed, also you get a memory leak (also take care of the case when the value changes)

Answer (score 0):

If you [render your component using separate render function](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/render-function.html), this is easy:

```js
export default {
    props: {
        eventName: {
            type: String,
        },
    },
    render: function (createElement) {
        return createElement('my-component', {
            on: {
                [this.eventName]: (event) => {
                    console.log('Received event!')
                }
            }
        })
    }
}
```

Render functions also come with ability to dynamically specify a name for the component, if that is also required for your app

Comment: This looks really promising. I'm just wondering if it's possible to use this in Nuxt?